# Is there a contradiction between these two definitions about an op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, resistors

This image shows the inside of an op-amp:

[image]

But I read in a website that:

> The standard 741 Op-amp circuit contains 20 transistors and 11 resistors.

**Why does this image does not show these transistors and resistors if an op-amp consists of 20 transistors and 11 resistors?**

Comment: Because the first image is just a general idealized model of an op amp. One realization of an op amp would be a 741 Op amp with transistors and resistors inside.

Comment: That image shows a simplified mathematical model of an opamp.

Comment: Question brief and clear. Answers adequate and upvoted. Learning experience. Close reasons given inappropriate. --> Close queue cleared.

Answer (score 8):

No there is no contradiction.

The image is a simplified model or a block diagram how an op-amp ideally works.

An op amp can be made out of discrete components, such as vacuum tubes or transistors and passives. The 741 is an integrated circuit which contains all components to make a complete op amp module as an IC.

You can easily find the internal schematics of a 741 op amp, such as the Wikipedia article on op amps.

Comment: Is say the VCVS model shows how the op-amp behaves. The transistor model shows how it works.

Answer (score 5):

**why this image does not show these transistors and resistors if an op-amp consist of 20 transistors and 11 resistors?**

Here is an important saying that you should keep in mind:

**All models are wrong. Some are useful.**

It's called a behavioral model, not a physical model (and it's a simplified behavioral model, at that). At this level of discourse, the makeup of the internal structure simply doesn't matter. It can use BJTs (bipolar junction transistors), or it can use FETs, or, for all you care, magic smoke. What is important is that it shows very high gain and a non-zero output impedance.

This is useful when doing analysis of well-behaved, small-signal circuits. It doesn't matter how the gain is produced, and *worrying* about it will just get in your way.

Sometimes, that behavioral model will lead you astray. For instance, if the real op amp being used has +/- 5 volt supplies, it cannot produce more than +/- 5 volts at the output. So if you have a gain of 10 inverter and apply 1 volt, the model you have been given will predict -10 volts at the output, and that is simply impossible. Furthermore, Aop is given as a single, scalar number. Real op amps have an Aop which varies with frequency.

All of that is true, but it's irrelevant to the things which you will learn using that model. Adding in 20 transistors and 11 resistors will not, at your current level of understanding, help you in the slightest, and will actually interfere with your education.

You have to learn to walk before you can learn to run.

Comment: George Box +1 :-) . But +1 anyway.